# Keep full precision with json.load

Tags: python, json

in Python, I read in some arrays with json.load.

```
z = pd.DataFrame()
with open('path/file.json') as f:
     data = json.load(f)
for x in data['y']:
    z = z.append(pd.DataFrame(x))
```

However, when I compare read-in numbers in the pandas dataframe z with original one numbers (json file and upstream workflow), I see, that the original full precision numbers where cut to the 6th digit und also converted to exponential format, where applicable. This is leading to wrong results in my downstream processing

How can I preserve full precision format with json.load?

Comment: Are you sure that the precision is actually lost? Did you check? Because when you print floats in python, it stores far more precision than what is displayed.

Comment: Concrete sample please.

Comment: Please show us a `json` file that demonstrates the problem. Otherwise, you do not give us enough detail to help you. Until then, instead of `print(num)` or such, try `print(repr(num))` to show better how the number is stored in Python.

Comment: I agree with @Kevin. Using numpy: `x = 1 + np.finfo(float).eps  # maximal precision needed`. Then do `j = json.dumps(x); y = json.loads(j), x == y` prints `True`.

Comment: When I cat into the file, I can see the full precision. I cannot dump my case file here (too big) and it is confidential.

Comment: *Some* sample will be enough. Four different people have given various hints and asked for various things, and all you can do is repeat yourself?

Comment: We don't need to see your real data, but we _do_ need to see a _small_ sample of data that we can use to reproduce this problem. If you don't add such data to your question then it's likely to get closed.

Comment: ok, FMHTMitchell's code reproduces the same number, but cuts all digits to. 1.0 vs. 
1.0000000000000002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I put the blame on the wrong one. JSON does correctly the job. The "problem" is, that the standard precision of pandas is 6. You may change the precision by

```
pd.set_option('precision', 10).
```

Thank you for your comments into the right direction!